# Is ASP.NET Identity user id public?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I suppose it's safe to say user id is a public value and there is nothing wrong with exposing it as a parameter to my web api endpoint?

My reasoning is that it is already made public since it's included in JWT. Am I correct?

My application uses implicit authorization flow with oidc + pkce.

EDIT:

As Alejadro said in the comment below this is probably right. Clarification: This question concerns the Identity system in intself, although I appreciate the mentioned broader context.

Comment: It depends. While in itself there is no problem showing it, it may disclose some information you might want to conceal. For example, an autoincrementing id gives an approximation of how many registered users are.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my question - I asked in the context of ASP Identity itself. The rest is my "business layer" and is out of the scope of this question.